# Extjs 5.1.1 does not work on server production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs, parameters, extjs5

I'm developing an application with MVC Asp.NET 5 Extjs 5.1.1. In development environment it works fine.

I have the next problem:

my extjs model:

```
Ext.define('Wts.model.DailyRegister', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    {
        name: 'Year',
        type: 'int',
        mapping: 'DailyRegister.Year'
    },
    {
        name: 'Month',
        type: 'int',
        mapping: 'DailyRegister.Month'
    },
    {
        name: 'Project_ID',
        type: 'int',
        mapping: 'DailyRegister.Project_ID'
    },
    {
        name: 'Project_Name',
        type: 'string'
    },
    {
        name: 'Activity_ID',
        type: 'int',
        mapping: 'DailyRegister.Activity_ID'
    },
    {
        name: 'Activity_Name',
        type: 'string'
    },
    {
        name: 'Activity_UnitCost',
        type: 'number'
    },
    {
        name: 'Date',
        type: 'date',
        dateFormat: 'MS'
    },
    {
        name: 'ActivityType',
        type: 'int'
    },
    {
        name: 'Employee_ID',
        type: 'int',
        mapping: 'DailyRegister.Employee_ID'
    },
    {
        name: 'Day',
        type: 'int',
        mapping: 'DailyRegister.Day'
    },
    {
        name: 'WorkedHours',
        type: 'number',
        mapping: 'DailyRegister.WorkedHours',
        convert: function(value, record) { 
            if (record.get('ActivityType') == 1) {
                return window.convertNumberToTime(value);
            }
            return value;
        },
        serialize: function(value, record) { /
            if (record.get('ActivityType') == 1) {
                return window.convertTimeToNumber(value);
            }
            return value;
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'Sum',
        type: 'number',
        mapping: 'DailyRegister.Sum'
    },
    {
        name: 'Comments',
        type: 'string',
        mapping: 'DailyRegister.Comments',
    },
    {
        name: 'ItWasSended',
        type: 'boolean',
        mapping: 'DailyRegister.ItWasSended',
    },
    {
        name: 'DataRange',
        type: 'bool'
    },
    {
        name: 'EndDate',
        type: 'date',
        dateFormat: 'MS'
    }
]
```

});

When I try to create a DailyRegister on development environment

[image]

**When I try to create a DailyRegister on production environment, field WorkedHours is not sent** Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

- Ddebug under testing code. Plz use "sencha app build testing" to build the testing package.
- Remove one of the "convert"/"serialise" config to see whether your http params contain the "WorkedHours" param.